# Как получить url страницы после ее загрузки AJAX-ом?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

В цикле идет получение страниц для последующего анализа:

```
for (var i2 = 0; i2 < linksData.length; i2++){
  $.get(linksData[i2], function(html_data) {

   console.log(linksData[i2]); //Выводит undefined

  //Обрабатываем содержимое, парсим и так далее, но как получить адрес страницы с которой работаем? Мне это надо, чтобы 2+2 сложилось.

  }, 'html');
}
```

Пишу приложение, которое спарсивает нужную пользователю информацию с разных сайтов и подает в удобном виде. Есть категории, к каждой из которых привязаны массивы ссылок **linksData**, которые время от времени обрабатываются, для этого нужно знать, какую ссылку мы обработали, чтобы свести полученные данные и категорию пользователя.

Comment: Что за вопрос такой странный. Как получить то, что у вас же прямо на странице написано?

Ну, допустим, вот так:

    var res = "http://mysite.ru/page.html";
    $.get(res, function(html_data) {
    console.log(res);
    //Обрабатываем содержимое, парсим и так далее, но как получить адрес страницы с которой работаем? Мне это надо, чтобы 2+2 сложилось.
    
    }, 'html');

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, опять я все упростил и не понятно. В цикле идет получение страниц.

Comment: @Ilja так поправьте, чтобы было понятно, и посмотрим.
Приведите весь код.

Comment: @Ilja, значит делайте то же самое, что написал @Vladislav Pyatkov, только в цикле :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, я еще с ума не сошел :), это первое, что я попробовал, выдает undefined в коносоль.

Comment: @MasterAlex, @Ilja, я понял, в чём дело, не хватает понимания замыкания.

@Ilja, {} - это не делает замыкание, а вот это делает function() {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом случае можно так сделать:

```
for (var i2 = 0; i2 < linksData.length; i2++){
  (function() {
    var res = linksData[i2];

    $.get(res, function(html_data) {
    console.log(res);
    //Обрабатываем содержимое, парсим и так далее, но как получить адрес страницы с которой работаем? Мне это надо, чтобы 2+2 сложилось.
    }, 'html');
  })();
}
```

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, спасибо, работает. Надо будет еще поизучать javascript, чтобы так не тупить, как я. :)

Comment: Чуть проще оборачивать не целиком тело цикла, а только коллбек.
Очень неочевидное объяснение, даёт ответ, но не даёт разъяснения, почему i2 в коллбеке всегда == linksData.length, то есть за пределами массива.